# Passing numpy ndarray to a C extension of python and returning a numpy ndarray from C extension

Tags: python, c, numpy, extension-methods, numpy-ndarray

I am writing a C extension of python3 with two functions; one takes a numpy ndarray as one of the parameters, and the other returns an ndarray.

Also, I'm parsing arguments via `PyArg_ParseTuple`; I don't see how to specify ndarray among formats.

Could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? Python has great documentation on calling extension functions, and numpy has great documentation on the classes it defines.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I did. I don't see it addressing passing ndarray.

Comment: ndarray is a normal Python object

Comment: You probably want one of `O`, `O!` or `O&` as the type code.